# Framebuffer objects are not supported by this hardware (or driver)

Tags: processing

I'm trying to run OpenKinect using Processing. I'm pretty new to Processing and I'm not really sure what is happening. I followed the codes from this [page](https://shiffman.net/p5/kinect/) but I seem to be getting the error below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Framebuffer objects are not supported by this hardware (or driver) Read http://wiki.processing.org/w/OpenGL_Issues for help.
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL.init(PJOGL.java:428)
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL$DrawListener.init(PSurfaceJOGL.java:889)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.init(GLDrawableHelper.java:644)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.init(GLDrawableHelper.java:667)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$1.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:431)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1291)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
    at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:759)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:81)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:452)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$MainTask.run(FPSAnimator.java:178)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

How do I know which driver I need to install?(if there's any that I need to)

Comment: Are you sure this is an issue with the driver? What kind of graphics card do you have? Are you using the on board graphics? They typically support less OpenGL functionality

Comment: I have a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 Ti for my graphics card. But when I checked my graphics card driver, the driver wasn't installed properly so I guess that could be the problem.(Having trouble installing the Nvidia driver right now tho..)

Comment: Ok yeah, sounds like you didn't have the driver installed so your machine is/was defaulting to the onboard graphics.

Comment: @sabrinazuraimi what version of the Kinect are you using ? (Kinect Sensor V1 or Kinect Sensor v2 ?). It would be good if you could post a minimal version of your code(that isolates the problem) for easy testing